Universal way of extracting tag values out of XML document to a List<string>
I have a XML document being loaded into a webpage representing a single client looking like this:
 <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?-->
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <document>
            <Name>Pablo</Name>
            <Surname>Salamanca</Surename>
            <Age>68</Age>
            <Gender>M</Gender>
        </document>
    </body> 
 </html>

Resulting page show data and nothing more like this:
Pablo Salamnca 68 M
Things to keep in mind before answering:

There are nigh 15 different templates for XML structure. Meaning there is no standardization. One person may have a different order of information presented and other may have different information presented entirely. The structure of XML is not changed, only the TAG values and their order.

Each client has depending on a template 68 - 278 (exactly) attributes/elements in their respective XML.


I need a List<string> into which I would parse the TAG values of the person only. Meaning I would have a list like this:
List[0] = "Name"

List[1] = "Surname"

List[2] = "Age"

List[3] = "Gender"

...

This is the code which I have ready:
 var url = _urlMaker.GetUrl();
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
 string xml = client.DownloadString(url);

 int n = 2;
 List<string> xmlSplit = xml
     .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
     .Skip(n)
     .ToList();

 xml = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, xmlSplit);

Here I need a universal way of parsing the TAGs (or tags' values) into a List of strings please. The best case scenario is parsing only tag values surrounding the person so no words like "document" "html" etc. get parsed, but I can probably work with the field which has these values. I did try, among several other ways, to work with document by splitting it into nodes but that has went amiss.
Side note:
The reason for the whole splitting string into a list of strings and removing 1st two lines is due to an issue brought up to me by another engineer. The document from which I am parsing is apparently an HTML and Visual Studio refuses to parse it entirely. So I have forced it to look like XML which works and now in a different part of my code the parsing of values is successful.
I could just use XmlDocument.GetElements like this:
...code...
...loading data into something like a XML document....
        XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("title");

But I cannot since I have no idea with what to replace "title".

Linq2Xml is probably worth a look.

I have tried but I am pretty new to this so I failed miserably.

Are only the tag-names different or is the entire structure - meaning the nesting of the tags also - different? Could becomre pretty hard withoiut any sort of structure.

structure should remain the same, it is just names and their order. I should edit my question. Thank you!

XmlNodeList docList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("document"); XmlNodeList nameList = docList[0].GetElementsByTagName("Name"); string name = nameList[0].innerText; I don't know .net but may it works :-p

This is the third time the same question was asked. LINQ-to-XML was mentioned and even demonstrated all 3 times. Why ask again? BTW what you posted isn't XML. It's HTML or more precisely XHTML. You can use any XML serializer as long as it's well formed. If it's not, you'll have to tweak it. If it's malformed because eg </html> is missing, no serializer will work. String splitting is never an option when XML is involved

The posted example contains no title. HTML pages do have title elements though. This page has <title>c# - Universal way of extracting ....</title>. Perhaps, instead of trying to parse HTML as if it was XML you should use an HTML parser like AngleSharp. HTML parsers are very permissive and can handle badly formed HTML up to a point

If you do use LINQ-to-XML and parse the text into an XDocument you can use doc.Descendants("title").First() to get the title element. Check Find Descendants with a specific name

Hello mr. Kanavos. Thank you, I get you try to help .. but.. my other 2 questions are regarding a similiar yet not same issue. 1st one was poorly worded and thusly deleted (and no constructive answer was provided there). 2nd got the needed result. Just telling me "use LING-xml" will not cut it. I know I have and I have tride, I am just new to this and do not know exactly how hence I need somone to fill in the code for me. Or give me a good source of info. learn.microsoft usually has a vague examples of not similiar character. doc.Descendats ive tried but thak you its helpful still.

" String splitting is never an option when XML is involved" I felt like this was given and I am trying to avoid it as much as possible. Thanks for assuring me

You can try the following method to get dynamic person's data as a string.
It is using SQL Server, and its XML and XQuery functionality.
The XQuery below is retrieving all XML elements values under the <document> XML element regardless of their dynamic nature.
You can create a one line stored procedure in SQL Server that accepts a single XML data type parameter, and call it from c#.
SQL
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?-->
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <document>
            <Name>Pablo</Name>
            <Surname>Salamanca</Surname>
            <Age>68</Age>
            <Gender>M</Gender>
        </document>
    </body>
</html>';

SELECT @xml.query('data(//document/*)').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS result;

SELECT c.value('local-name(.)', 'SYSNAME') AS result
FROM @xml.nodes('//document/*') AS t(c);

Output #1
Pablo Salamanca 68 M

Output #2



result




Name


Surname


Age


Gender




hi, i need tag values not the attributes. meaning that the output has to be "Name", "surname", "creditDebt".. et

I updated the answer. Another one liner.

I would use Xml Linq and put results into a DataTable instead of a List.  The Datatable contains both the name of the tag and the value instead of just the value.
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement document = doc.Descendants("document").FirstOrDefault();
            DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
            foreach(XElement element in document.Elements())
            {
                string name = element.Name.LocalName;
                string value = (string)element;
                if(!dt.Columns.Contains(name))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(name);
                }
                newRow[name] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

